# MySQL Workbench not showing schemas in Models

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL Workbench, so this could be a basic error on my part, but I am not sure what to do.

I have imported data (both using Data Import as well as running a script that includes schema creation) and I can see the schema exists in the Navigator. Likewise, I can run SQL queries on the schema with no problems.

However, when I go to File -> New Model, the schema is not there. I tried downloading another .sql file, created a schema for it and have the same problem.

Summary: I have schemas in MySQL Workbench that are not showing up in the Model section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris M Perry answered this on Twitter for me:
"In any tab, you can click database -> reverse engineer and then follow the steps in selecting the schema."